# MySQL - Multiple commands

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

How do I do multiple commands in mysql at the same time with each call? Is it possible? Do I separate them with ';'?

I share a database. It is in the US, while I am in the UK. I need absolute precision with my DATETIMEs. I cannot alter the cnf file. Other people may be setting their own prefered time zones between my calls. So to make sure I am constantly storing and retreiving my dates to my php as UTC times, I planned on doing a multi-command with each MySql call.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SET @@session.time_zone='+00:00'; "
                    . "UPDATE mytable SET MyDate=:MyDate WHERE "
                    . "UserId=:UserId");
$stmt->execute(array(':MyDate' => $MyDate, ':UserId' => $UserId));
```

Note: $MyDate is already UTC.

Do you see I am trying to sneak in an extra command "SET @@session.time_zone='+00:00'" before any DATETIME related MySql stuff? But I do not know if the ';' is the right way to do this, or if it can be done.

Comment: why not just try and see if it works? it should work fine as far as i know

Comment: I do not know is the SET @@session.time.... is working, as I live in the UTC timezone. I need conformation, this is the correct way of doing things.

Comment: just try a different command or change the command to a different timezone? like i said i'm pretty sure it is but you can test this out super easily

Comment: Thanks Jester; good idea.

Comment: UK is not UTC.  In the summer, it's UTC+1 for daylight saving time.  Use `'Europe/London'` to identify the time zone if you actually want UK Time.  If you want UTC, then just use `'UTC'`.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the clarification. (You are right, I am presently on +1).